# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in redhen_activity.module on line 608

Tags: 7

After migrating from dev to prod on Bluehost when I run `update.php` I get a 500 error and I get the below error in error in `error_log`.

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in
>   redhen_activity.module on line 608

This is D7 with the latest update to the Open Outreach Distribution. The odd thing is that my dev site (running as a subdomain) works just fine.

Comment: Your version of php isn't high enough, needs to be 5.3 or higher if it's an anonymous function on that line

Comment: Please check the PHP version on your dev and prod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 608 contains anonymous function.

```
$filtered = array_filter($message_types, function($var) {
  return strpos($var, 'redhen_') !== FALSE;
});
```

[Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2467239#comment-9827915) is the good explanation from DanChadwick on Drupal.org. Let me quote it here as well.

> That line of code is an anonymous function. There are only 2 reasons I
>   know of why PHP choke on an anonymous function.
>
> 1) Use of PHP < 5.3, where anonymous functions aren't supported.
>
> 2) Use of an opcode cache that doesn't support anonymous function. APC
>   works. Searching the issue queue will reveal another that doesn't,
>   whose name escapes me at the moment.
>
> I'd venture that your other functioning sites either
>
> a) aren't displaying components
>
> b) are using an older version of webform,
>
> c) are using a newer version of PHP or
>
> d) aren't using the same op code cache.

So the best solution is to upgrade your PHP version.

To check your PHP version, either:

1. use the PHP cli `php -v` or
2. use the `phpinfo()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using PHP 5.2 or earlier, which doesn't support closures. You can find out which version of PHP you're using  [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

Lindly upgrade to PHP 5.3+, or use [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php), or write a static function and pass it as a [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. Unknown to me, Bluehost downgraded my PHP version. When they upgraded it to 5.6.24 everything worked. I battled this error for weeks! It was very frustrating!